# Moved DC Server and all FSMO Roles, Demoted old DC, but now it can't connect

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

[image]I moved the DC FSMO roles to a new DC (2012 R2) server, seemed like everything was fine, then I demoted the old one as I was having issues.  Then once it was demoted, I can no longer connect to the AD services from within the DC controller.
[image]

Here are the steps that I took to transfer from the old DC controller before I demoted it.
https://blog.robseder.com/2015/09/01/switching-the-primary-domain-controller-in-active-directory-fsmo/

How can I fix this?  I have checked the services and everything seems to be running.

Comment: Did your new server hold the global catalogue?

Comment: Check all your Network Adapters on all your domain controller and ensure that DNS settings in TCP\IP setting are not pointing to your demoted DC for DNS just in case. Maybe a reboot of the DCs too just some quick thoughts. You might consider changing the DHCP settings on your DHCP server to ensure the IP of the demoted DCs isn't causing the issue at this level for IP assigned by DHCP. Check here too: https://www.petri.com/forums/forum/microsoft-networking-services/active-directory/64863-active-directory-naming-information-cannot-be-located-because-the-specified-domain-d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DC is not a member server nor stand alone server. So, once demoted, a DC is not a part of any domain.

Therefore, I think your former DC is now at a workgroup, thus, ADUC and other tools don't have meaning since there is no domain.

Try add it to the domain and see if it solves your problem.
IT IS BEST IF YOU CHANGE IT'S NAME BEFORE YOU DO IT OR DO A METADATA CLEAN UP SINCE THERE MIGHT BE SRV RECORDS THAT WILL POINT TO THE OLD NAME.

Comment: It's been a while since I have done the opposite of what is now dcpromo on a DC, but I am pretty sure it is a domain member after it is depromoted.

Comment: I can confirm that when demoted a DC is a member of the domain it was a DC for as I just happened to need to demote a DC.

Answer (score 2):

Typically a domain controller will have itself as the DNS server for the network interface. This is less than optimal, but it works in certain circumstances. Since you demoted the server, it probably no longer has a functional DNS configuration. Change the IP address of the DNS server on the network interface to the new domain controller.

Comment: I also tried to point the DNS to the DNS server (AD Server).

Answer (score 1):

First check DNS and the associated IP address.  If it is AD - Integrated DNS then IP address should be same as DC's.

After checking the above, run the below tool named esentutl.exe by accessing server in DSRM (Directory Service Restore Mode).  The data base may have been corrupted.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875590(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is ADUC still trying to use the old DC? If so, then that's your problem. Right click at the top and select "Change Domain Controller".

[image]

Comment: I tried that but it can't find a domain controller.